# Reading macros in an Excel file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I've got an Excel file (supplied by someone else) that opens with the message

```
 This file contains Visual Basic macros.
```

I'd like to look at the macros within the file - they contain code that I would like to be able to see. Once I've opened the file and allowed the macros, can I then read the Visual Basic code they contain?

I have tried looking under `Tools > Macros`, but I can't see any macros there, so perhaps they are hidden to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor window. There you can browse for any modules that contain VBA code.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the 'Microsoft Developer Network' (MSDN) help files to [Show the Developer Tab on the Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx).

Then click the left-most icon on the Developer Tap to bring up the VBA editor window.
(Also possible with Alt+F11)

This method works for Excel Versions 2007 and 2010.

---

For Excel 2003 (which seems to be your version, if you talk about `Tools > Macros`)...

On the *Tools* menu, point to *Macro*, and then click *Visual Basic Editor* to bring up the same window as above.